# Converting string into date using C# in ASP.NET gets me a date an hour off. Why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I'm coding the following using VS2010, C#, ASP.NET:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-03-11T02:53:58-08:00"); //Date is taken from SQL database
string strDt = dt.ToString();   //Becomes: "3/11/2012 3:53:58 AM"
```

Is this April's fools joke from Microsoft?

Comment: Why are you parsing a string to datetime when the type of your field already **is** a datetime?

Comment: It's hard to explain in this context, let's just say that I'm simply converting from string to datetime (so forget about SQL database.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "incorrect" result (as darkmyst's answer explains) is caused by the fact that March 11, 2012, 2:38:58 AM, was not a valid date and time in areas of the United States and Canada that observe daylight saving time. Evidently, your code is running on a computer in one of these areas.

To convert a string to a `DateTime`, ignoring any time zone offset, you can call `DateTimeOffset.Parse` and then retrieve the `DateTime` component of the result:

```
DateTime dt = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2012-03-11T02:53:58-08:00").DateTime;
string strDt = dt.ToString();  // "3/11/2012 2:53:58 AM"
```

**UPDATE:** So what's the difference between `DateTime.Parse` and `DateTimeOffset.Parse` when the original string contains a time zone offset? Consider these two examples, which assume your current time zone is Pacific Time:

```
// Example 1: DateTime.Parse(String)
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2012-03-11T06:00:00-04:00");
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("o"));  // 2012-03-11T03:00:00.0000000-07:00
```

`DateTime.Parse` uses the offset to adjust the parsed date and time to **local** time. Note that the time has changed from 6 AM to 3 AM, reflecting the conversion from Eastern Daylight Time (UTC-04:00) to Pacific Daylight Time (UTC-07:00). In your question, the time changed because `DateTime.Parse` automatically adjusted the time from Pacific Standard Time (UTC-08:00) to Pacific Daylight Time (UTC-07:00).

```
// Example 2: DateTimeOffset.Parse(String)
DateTimeOffset dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2012-03-11T06:00:00-04:00");
Console.WriteLine(dto.DateTime.ToString("o"));  // 2012-03-11T06:00:00.0000000
Console.WriteLine(dto.Offset);                  // -04:00:00
```

`DateTimeOffset.Parse` is simpler. It just returns a `DateTimeOffset` value whose `DateTime` and `Offset` properties are set to the parsed date, time, and offset. **But beware:** If the time zone offset in the string doesn't match the time zone you want to work with, then you need to adjust the resulting date and time yourself.

Comment: Thanks. That actually worked. Can you explain how it works and I'll mark it as an asnwer?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It was very helpful. I wish they just labeled those APIs a little bit better.

Answer (score 4):

It's allowing for the Time Zone you are in.  The time string is in ISO8601 format with timezone.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: OK. Thanks. So how do I parse it without any reference to any time zone, etc. It clearly shows the date in the string. So how do I get the exact same thing in the DateTime?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a joke or a timezone issue. It's Daylight Savings Time. Google "Daylight Savings Time 2012", here's the result:

> Daylight Saving Time (United States) began Sunday, March 11, 2012, 2:00am, and ends Sunday, November 4, 2012, 2:00am.
>   Except Arizona and Hawaii. Move your clocks ahead 1 hour in spring and back 1 hour in fall ("Spring forward, fall back").

In other words, wherever daylight savings time is observed, there is no 2:53:58 AM on March 11th, 2012.  The clock skips over the 2 o'clock hour straight from 1:59:59 AM to 3:00:00AM. Why your sql datetime is not observing daylight savings time and the machine your c# is executing on is -- that's another issue..

Comment: OK, makes sense ... if it was DateTime.ParseWithRegardsToDaylightSaving() API, but not just a generic Parse! Anyway, it took me half a day to isolate this issue. So I'm close to resolving it.... Anyway, forget about SQL database. How do I simply convert a string to DateTime variable to exactly what it says in the string?

Comment: It may be that the server is an older version of Windows (2000 or 2003) that has not had patches applied to adjust to the changes in DST in 2007.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a "ParseWithRegardsToDaylightSaving()" method, but I tested your code with various hours surrounding your datetime and confirmed your experience and that it was a Daylight Savings issue. I'm still looking into a way to ignore it and force the datetime to what the string says.